# Assigning mongodb array element in a variable in pymongo

Tags: python, database, pymongo

i am making a self-project for practice but i am stuck at a point. I am not able to store the value of an element of an array of mongodb in a variable.

```
server = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
pokemon_python = server.pokemon_python
gonestarter = pokemon_python.gonestarter


bulba_health = gonestarter.find_one({"stats":{"$elemMatch":{"health": 15}}}, {"stats":{"$elemMatch":{"health": 15}}})


bulba_health = str(bulba_health["stats"])
print(f"Health: {bulba_health}")
```

the result is printed as Health: [{'health': 15}]

but the result i want is that only gives me Health: 15

Comment: Does `bulba_health["stats"][0]["health"]` get the value you want?

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs this worked i was stuck on this problem since yesterday.....Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current python code, you can access the value you want with:

```py
bulba_health["stats"][0]["health"]
```

`bulba_health["stats"]` retrieves the array values of the `"stats"` field:

```py
[{"health": 15}, ...]
```

`bulba_health["stats"][0]` retrieves the first element in the array:

```py
{"health": 15}
```

`bulba_health["stats"][0]["health"]` retrieves the value of the `"health"` field:

```py
15
```